# Regex: find text between two unknown tags

Tags: regex, match, validation

i have a string like this :

```
<!NAME!>Admin : <!NAME!><!MSG!>Hello Guys<!MSG!><!ADD-ACC!>BOSS<!ADD-ACC!>
```

I want to write a regex pattern that extracts text between two same tags like

```
<!NAME!>Admin : <!NAME!>
<!MSG!>Hello Guys<!MSG!>
<!ADD-ACC!>BOSS<!ADD-ACC!>
```

So i wrote this regex :

```
<!.*!>.*<!.*!>
```

But it gave me this result

```
<!NAME!>Admin : <!NAME!><!MSG!>Hello Guys<!MSG!><!ADD-ACC!>BOSS<!ADD-ACC!>
```

I understand why it did so, it is because

```
 <!NAME!> and <!ADD-ACC!> follows the regex pattern i am using.
```

So i was thinking of something like that in regex

```
<!XXX!>.*<!XXX!> where XXX is the same text between tags so that REGEX could find and extract those tags from text like how i want it to be done.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use backreference

```
(<!.*?!>).*?\1
```

---

`.*` is greedy quantifier which matches as **much** as possible

`.*?` is a lazy quantifier which matches as **less** as possible

`(<!.*?!>)` would capture a tag in **group 1**

We can refer to the captured value in **group 1** within regex using `\1`..So,`\1` refers to the first captured group value